# Setting IP to static results in some unreachable ports

Tags: server, 18.04, port-forwarding, webmin, virtualmin

I had Virtualmin running perfectly on my Ubuntu 18.04
I set a new internal static IP (Before it was DHCP) with netplan as following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.2.1/22]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

After that I forwarded all the necessary ports in my router. The router had a submask 255.255.255.0 so I changed it to 255.255.254.0

Now: the ports `22`, `465`, `587`, `3306` are still reachable and the ports `20`, `80`, `443`, `10000`, `20000` are closed now/ Err_Conn_Refused
(Checked with https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)
Before the IP change, all these ports were open and running.

```
https://localhost:10000
```

doesn't work either from a local network computer

Firewall seems to be OK, I tried to reinstall Virtualmin in the hope that it would reconfigure it correctly, no luck. I also tried to restore it and use dhcp again, but it's still the same error. I assigned 10 Gb ram to virtualmin, so it shouldn't be this either. Virtualmin is up and running, as far as I can understand.

---

As always,I did not look good enough at every single detail. But I think there are a lot of things that could be relevant to the problem that contains many details to look at. Apart of that:

The service Apache was not running all along.

I tried to start it and it gave an error. That's because I deleted the ssl cert files of some domains about 2 hours before I set up the static IP. Apache could not locate the SSL files and was therefore not able to start. edited the conf files and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this every which way for the last month. Solution:

Virtualmin will only work if networking is setup in webmin on 18.04.

Meaning setup netplan only from Webmin-Networking-Network Configuration. Then the proper readable netplan .yaml file will be created.